# How can a server know which session belongs to which client?

Tags: asp.net

In my office we have multiple computers and when we check from a remote server what is the IP of each computer, since they all come out of the same router, I get the same IP.

This started me thinking about how the server knows what session belongs to which client?
What identifies one computer from another in the eyes of the server when the IP address is similar?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Server sends a cookie to the user with a session id. This session id identifies the user to the server. ASP.NET can also append the session id to the query string if cookies are turned off.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163730.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On each request made to server by the client a *TCP* connection is made with has common `IP` address in your case but different **port** and each client is differentiated on the bases of port to send the response back to the client. You can read more about TCP connections over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/366121/do-browsers-create-new-tcp-connections-for-each-http-requests).

If you are talking about HTTP session then they use cookies / query string in url to identifiy session, you can read more over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

**Session Identifiers**

> Sessions are identified by a unique identifier that can be read by
>   using the SessionID property. When session state is enabled for an
>   ASP.NET application, each request for a page in the application is
>   examined for a SessionID value sent from the browser. If no SessionID
>   value is supplied, ASP.NET starts a new session and the SessionID
>   value for that session is sent to the browser with the response. By
>   default, SessionID values are stored in a cookie. However, you can
>   also configure the application to store SessionID values in the URL
>   for a "cookieless" session, [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: Good old NAT: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756722%28v=ws.10%29.aspx